# How can I calculate the correct offset for fancyhdr when using geometry to change layout?

Tags: fancyhdr, geometry, calculations

I have a document with the following configuration:

1. a custom layout is defined using `geometry` in the preamble;
2. custom headers/footers are defined using `fancyhdr` in the preamble;
3. an alternative layout is defined right after `\begin{document}` for the first part of the document;
4. the document's default layout is later restored.

Because the margins and width of the text block vary, I need to define a suitable offset for `\fancyhdr` so that the rules it draws start in the correct place. Initially, I thought I could easily do this:

```
width of 'total body' in alternative layout - width of 'total body' in initial layout
```

minus an inch to account for LaTeX's default offset.

That is, I thought that something like

```
\fancyheadoffset[lh]{.1\paperwidth-1in}%
```

should do the trick.

However, this doesn't work:

[image: incorrect offset]

Note that adding `showframe` tends to mask the problem. Indeed, I can get the correct header rule to be drawn by adding

```
\makeatletter
\usepackage{atbegshi}%
\renewcommand*{\Gm@pageframes}{%
  \moveright\@themargin%
  \vb@xt@\z@{%
    \vb@xt@\z@{%
     \vskip\topmargin\vb@xt@\z@{\vss}%
     \vskip\headheight\vb@xt@\z@{\vss\Gm@hruled}%
     \vskip\headsep\vb@xt@\z@{\vss}%
     \@tempdima\textwidth
     \advance\@tempdima by \marginparsep
     \advance\@tempdima by \marginparwidth
     \vb@xt@\z@{\vss}%
     \vskip\footskip\vb@xt@\z@{\vss}%
     \vss}%
  }%
}
\AtBeginShipout{\setbox\AtBeginShipoutBox=\vbox{%
    \baselineskip\z@skip\lineskip\z@skip\lineskiplimit\z@
    \Gm@pageframes\box\AtBeginShipoutBox}}
\makeatother
```

to the preamble. (It is horrible on pages which should use `empty` or `plain`, of course.)

How can I get the correct offset and correct results without, obviously, using this hacked version of `showframe`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\geometry{headheight=12pt,marginparwidth=45mm,hmarginratio=4:1,vscale=.8,hscale=.7,verbose}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{headheight=12pt,scale=.8,marginparwidth=0pt,marginparsep=0pt}%
\fancyheadoffset[lh]{.1\paperwidth-1in}%
\section{Kant}
\kant[1-6]
\restoregeometry
\fancyheadoffset[lh]{0pt}%
\section{More Kant}
\kant[7-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it work with `showframe`? If I make the rule thicker with `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}` to differentiate it from the frame, the offset still looks wrong.

Comment: @Guho Yes. I just discovered this, I think, by 'aping' the effect of the rule with showframe. That is, I think you're right and I was just coming back to edit here. You can see you're right if you add `\maketitle`. (You still get a perfect rule where fancyhdr does nothing.)

Comment: @Guho Try `\fancyheadoffset[lh]{0pt}%` ??!!!

Comment: @Guho People will think I asked this deliberately in order to answer. It seems absolutely obvious to me now, even though it seemed deeply puzzling 10 minutes ago ;).

Comment: Related Question: [fancyhdr ignores newgeometry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/402278/4301).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, so I guess in retrospect this is obvious. The correct offset is zero.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\geometry{headheight=12pt,marginparwidth=45mm,hmarginratio=4:1,vscale=.8,hscale=.7,verbose}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{headheight=12pt,scale=.8,marginparwidth=0pt,marginparsep=0pt}%
\fancyheadoffset[lh]{0pt}%
\title{title}\author{author}\maketitle
\section{Kant}
\kant[1-6]
\restoregeometry
\fancyheadoffset[lh]{0pt}%
\section{More Kant}
\kant[7-10]
\end{document}
```

[image: correct offset]

The difference between leaving the offset at its default value of zero and setting it to zero is that the latter, but not the former, causes `fancyhdr` to recalculate things *with the dimensions as currently defined*. That is, it forces a recalculation in light of the changed values of those dimensions following the installation of the new layout with `\newgeometry`.