# fancyhdr ignores newgeometry

Tags: horizontal-alignment, header-footer, fancyhdr, geometry

It seems that `fancyhdr` ignores the setting of `\newgeoemtry`. That is, the settings made upon loading the `geometry` package:

```
\usepackage[
    left=1.0em,
    right=1.0em,
    top=1.0cm,
    bottom=1.0cm,
    paperheight=11.0in,
    paperwidth=8.5in
]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}% clear headers
\fancyfoot{}% clear footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% eliminate horizontal line
\fancyfoot[RO, LE]{Page \thepage}
```

work fine with the page number being on the right hand side as required:

[image]

But, if the `\fancyfoot` is set, and *then* the geometry is modified:

```
\usepackage[
    paperheight=11.0in,
    paperwidth=8.5in
]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}% clear headers
\fancyfoot{}% clear footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% eliminate horizontal line
\fancyfoot[RO, LE]{Page \thepage}

\newgeometry{
    left=1.0em,
    right=1.0em,
    top=1.0cm,
    bottom=1.0cm,
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}% clear headers
\fancyfoot{}% clear footers
\fancyfoot[RO, LE]{Page \thepage}
```

the footer does not end up on the right as requested.

[image]

### Notes:

- The reason for the two step process is that the `\usepacakge` and the `fancy` settings are from a common .sty files that I use. Then for one particular case, I want a different geometry so the cleanest solution is to use `\newgometry` to modify the settings.
- One solution of course is to set a flag before the packages are loaded and then adjust the settings at `\usepackage` time. I'd prefer not to do this as then the it seperates the specfic settings from where they are required.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{book}

%% -------------------------------------------- Standard packages
\usepackage{xcolor}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[
%% Setting these here work, however I would prefer to do this later via \newgoemetry
%    left=1.0em,
%    right=1.0em,
%    top=1.0cm,
%    bottom=1.0cm,
    paperheight=11.0in,
    paperwidth=8.5in
]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}% clear headers
\fancyfoot{}% clear footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% eliminate horizontal line
\fancyfoot[RO, LE]{Page \thepage}

%% -------------------------------------------- Cusomizations
\newgeometry{
    left=1.0em,
    right=1.0em,
    top=1.0cm,
    bottom=1.0cm,
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}% clear headers
\fancyfoot{}% clear footers
\fancyfoot[RO, LE]{Page \thepage}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

Comment: it doesn't ignore geometry, it uses the settings at the time that the page head is set. You could use `\AtBeginDocument{....}` around the fancyhdr settings so they happen after the geometry settings)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Applying `\AtBeginDocument{}` to the _initial_ settings seems to work. But, that also seems to imply that changing geometry mid document wont work with `fancyhdr`. Is there no way to reset the `fancy` settings?

Comment: the way to change the page head mid document is to define multiple page styles and use `\pagestyle{zzz}` where you want a change.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I can't seem to get that to work _without_ removing the _initial_ fancy settings, even with `\AtBeginDocument{\pagestyle{mypagestyle}}`.

Comment: you would need to adjust the geometry before defining the pagestyle (and adjust it back) or poke into the fancyhdr definition and reset its lengths to match the new textwidth

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299767/43317: `\newgeometry{...}` followed by `\fancyheadoffset[lh]{0pt}` seems to work.

Comment: @esdd: Yep, that resolved the issue in my full test case. Do you want to post an answer? Not sure that this is an exact duplicate of the where you got this answer, even if the answer is the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using one of the commands `\fancyhfoffset`, `\fancyheadoffset` or `\fancyfootoffset` the `\headwidth` will be recalculated based on the current parameters even if you use the default value `0pt` for the offset.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[
    paperheight=11.0in,
    paperwidth=8.5in
]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[RO, LE]{Page \thepage}

\newgeometry{
    left=1.0em,
    right=1.0em,
    top=1.0cm,
    bottom=1.0cm,
}
\fancyfootoffset{0pt}% <- recalculate \headwidth

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]